# Questions on MQTT on_log output

Tags: python, mqtt

I just started learning mqtt. I am using paho.mqtt for python and while logging the subscriber using the function below

```
def on_log(client, userdata, level, buff): 
    print(buff)
```

I saw this being printed out

```
Sending PUBREC (Mid: 4)
Received PUBREL (Mid: 4)
Sending PUBCOMP (Mid: 4)
```

The number after Mid keeps on increasing as I send more messages. I tried switching to qos=0 and this stopped appearing. So I'll assume it has something to do with how qos 2 sends the data exactly once.

What exactly is the number being shown?
Is it bad that the number after mid keeps on increasing?
If so how can I stop the number from continuously increasing without a limit?

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with MQTT's [qualities of service](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/). With `qos=0` it is correct that you don't see this log entries anymore since there is no 4-part handshake used

Comment: Define "bad" and what you want to "Stop happening"

Comment: "Mid" = Message Identifier; in the [MQTT 3.1.1 spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718025) this is called a "Packet Identifier" (and is not sent when `QOS=0`) - previous versions of the spec used the term ["Message Identifier"](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#msg-id).

Comment: From what I read from the link given, I guess the Mid that keeps increasing doesn't matter as it must be unique?

Comment: It has to be unique until "the Client has processed the corresponding acknowledgement packet" so reuse is possible. Many libraries do just increase [by one each time](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2564) because its unlikely that there will be 65535 messages in flight. What you are seeing is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Mid` you are seeing is the "Message Identifier" ([MQTT 3.1 and earlier](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#msg-id)) or "Packet Identifier"([MQTT 3.1.1 and later](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718024)).

This is a number that uniquely identifies the message (whilst the delivery handshake is in progress). You saw:

```
Sending PUBREC (Mid: 4)
Received PUBREL (Mid: 4)
Sending PUBCOMP (Mid: 4)
```

This indicates that a message with the ID 4 was received at QOS 2 (happened before the bit of log you show). From there the handshake is:

- The receiver (you) sends a [`PUBREC`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800421)
- When the publisher receives the `PUBREC` it sends a [`PUBREL`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718053)
- Finally upon receiving the `PUBREL` the receiver sends a [`PUBCOMP`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800431) to complete the transaction.

The ID is needed in each packet so the broker can tell what message the acknowledgement relates to (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14062788/11810946) for more info). The above is explained well in [this article](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-6-mqtt-quality-of-service-levels/).

QOS 0 messages are fire and forget so there is no acknowledgment and thus no message ID is needed. The [spec states](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718025) "A PUBLISH Packet MUST NOT contain a Packet Identifier if its QoS value is set to 0.". This is why you did not see it when you set `qos=0`.

QOS 1 messages do include an ID but the handshake is simpler (the receiver just sends a [`PUBACK`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800416)).

In order to provide a unique identifier the [Paho Python client](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L2564) starts with 1 and then increases this each time an ID is needed (looping back to 1 when it reaches 65536). In theory this could result in a conflict but its very unlikely that you would have 65536 messages in flight at any one time (but this can happen; particularly when the connection is down and messages are being queued).

So what you are seeing is expected and not something you need to try and fix!